# jQuery with Ajax request using GET not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, get, dropdownbox

I'm trying to use jquery with an ajax request to send the selection value of a dropdown list so different checkboxes can be displayed depending on the choice.

I was using this and it worked, but was sending the GET request twice and thought there must be a more efficient way:

```
success: function(html) {
  window.location.href= "search.php?industry=" + industry + "";
}
```

The GET request on the code below works and the checkboxes are displayed but the form repeats itself and I don't understand why. (image - https://ibb.co/j7Ag7m)

search.php is where all the code is, I tried saving the checkboxes part of the form in a different file e.g. url: "searchData.php" but the same thing happened.

Can someone tell me please where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['industry'])) {
  $request = $_GET[‘industry’];
  // insert to database here works
}
?>

<form id="skillsSelectForm" role="form" method="get">
  <select id="industry" name="industry">
    <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Charity">Charity</option>
    <option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
  </select>

  <script>
  $('#industry').change(function() {
    var industry = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "search.php",
      data: { industry: industry },
      success: function(data) {
        $("#results").html(data);
      }
    });
  });
  </script>

  <div id="results"></div>

  <?php
  // change checkboxes displayed based on $request
  if(isset($request)) {
    foreach ($allskills as $skill):
      if($request == $skill['industry']) {
        echo '<label for="'.$skill['skill'].'">
        <input type="checkbox" name="'.$skill['skill'].'" value="'.$skill['skill'].'">&nbsp; '.$skill['skill'].'</label>';
      }
    endforeach;
  }
  ?>

  <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">

</form>
```

Comment: all you have to is place the form in an `else`

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: use an `if else` statement instead of `if (isset($_GET`...this is an extremely simple answer and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to answer it.  You don't have a mistake in the code you just want it to do something different if the 'industry' is there.

Comment: I tried 
`if (isset($_GET['industry'])) {
// insert to db
} else {
// form
}`
if that's what you mean, but the selection doesn't work and the rest of the form still repeats

Comment: What should happen exactly when you click on the Search button? Because it seems that your are displaying some chekboxes again, but outside of the `results` div. That's confusing because you didn't provided enough/exact description. From where comes and how it looks `$allskills` array? Another question: what do you mean by "_insert to database here works_"? What are you inserting? Better provide the whole code, not pieces.

Answer (score 0):

I certainly can not say why your code failed, because your explanations are not so understandable for me, and because you provided incomplete codes or just code pieces. Sorry... :-)

Anyway, `window.location.href` is for sure not needed.

So, this is how I would do it.

---

### Solution 1

There is only the page search.php, with the form and no ajax request. If the checkbox is changed, just submit the form. So there will be two ways of submitting the form:

- By changing the combobox value;
- By clicking on the "searchButton".

In the PHP code on top of the page the two situations are differentiated by using:

```
$industry = 'Administration'; // Default combobox value.

if (isset($_POST['searchButton'])) { // Form was submitted by clicking on the "searchButton".
    $industry = $_POST['industry']; // Assign the chosen combobox value.
    // ...
} elseif (isset($_POST['industry'])) { // Form was submitted by changing the "industry" combobox value.
    $industry = $_POST['industry']; // Assign the chosen combobox value.
    // ...
}
```

I used "POST" for the form's method attribute (recommended). The rest is thoroughly commented in my code.

#### search.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Set the default industry. The value will be overwritten 
 * by the combobox value posted upon the form submission.
 */
$industry = 'Administration';

if (isset($_POST['searchButton'])) { // Form was submitted by clicking on the "searchButton".
    $industry = $_POST['industry']; // Assign the chosen combobox value.

    /*
     * Read the values of the posted skills checkboxes here. In the $_POST they are 
     * saved in an array like this:
     * 
     * [skills] => Array (
     *      [0] => 1
     *      [1] => 3
     * )
     */

    /*
     * Search in db and fetch the searching results into an array.
     * How you search is up to you. I'll use here just an array example.
     */
    $searchResults = [
        [
            'myarraykey1' => 13,
            'myarraykey2' => 'a value',
        //...
        ],
        [
            'myarraykey1' => 25,
            'myarraykey2' => 'other value',
        //...
        ],
        [
            'myarraykey1' => 37,
            'myarraykey2' => 'some other value',
        //...
        ],
    ];
} elseif (isset($_POST['industry'])) { // Form was submitted by changing the "industry" combobox value.
    $industry = $_POST['industry']; // Assign the chosen combobox value.
}

/*
 * If the form was not submitted yet, then $industry has the default value "Administration".
 * Otherwise, if the form was submitted (by clicking on the "searchButton"  or by changing 
 * the "industry" combobox value), $industry has the value of the submitted combobox value.
 * 
 * Fetch the skills list from the db for the selected industry with an sql statement like:
 * "SELECT id, name FROM skills WHERE industry = $industry".
 * Note: use prepared statements!
 * 
 * Let's say, if the form was submitted in one of the two ways, the industry chosen in the 
 * combobox was "Administration" or "Environment".
 * 
 * The if-elseif case bellow is just a simulation of getting skills array based on a non-existent db.
 * In your case, fetch the skills from db and define the $skills array, without any if-elseif statement.
 */
if ($industry === "Administration") {
    $skills = [
        [// 1st record
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Management',
        ],
        [// 2nd record
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Insurance',
        ],
        [// 3rd record
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Financial and control',
        ],
    ];
} elseif ($industry === "Environment") {
    $skills = [
        [// 1st record
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Agronomy',
        ],
        [// 2nd record
            'id' => 2,
            'name' => 'Ansible',
        ],
        [// 3rd record
            'id' => 3,
            'name' => 'Business Case Development',
        ],
    ];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#industry').on('change', function () {
                    $('#skillsSelectForm').submit();
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { padding: 30px; }
            button { padding: 5px 10px; font-size: 14px; background-color: #8daf15; color: #fff; border: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3>Skills Search</h3>

        <form id="skillsSelectForm" action="" method="post">

            <select id="industry" name="industry">
                <option value="Administration" <?php echo $industry === 'Administration' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                    Administration
                </option>
                <option value="Environment" <?php echo $industry === 'Environment' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                    Environment & Agriculture
                </option>
            </select>

            <br/><br/>

            <div id="skillsList">
                <?php
                foreach ($skills as $skill) {
                    $id = $skill['id'];
                    $name = $skill['name'];
                    ?>
                    <label for="skill_<?php echo $id; ?>">
                        <?php echo $name; ?>
                    </label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" id="skill_<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                    <br/>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>

            <br/>

            <button type="submit" name="searchButton">
                Search
            </button>

        </form>

        <?php
        if (isset($searchResults)) { // The form was not yet submitted by clicking on the "searchButton", so the array doesn't exist yet.
            ?>
            <br/><hr/><br/>

            <div id="searchResults">
                <?php
                if ($searchResults) { // Array is not empty, e.g. search results were found.
                    foreach ($searchResults as $searchResult) {
                        $myArrayValue1 = $searchResult['myarraykey1'];
                        $myArrayValue2 = $searchResult['myarraykey2'];
                        //...
                        ?>
                        <div class="search-result-record">
                            <?php echo $myArrayValue1; ?> &raquo; <?php echo $myArrayValue2; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                } else { // Array is empty, e.g. no search results found.
                    ?>
                    <span class="no-search-results">
                        No search results found
                    </span>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

---

### Solution 2

It is an elegant one actually. There are two pages:

- search.php with the form and two (!) ajax calls to fetch the skills list;
- getSkillsList.php with the code to fetch and display the skills list.

The first ajax fetches the skills list on document ready. The second ajax fetches the skills list on combobox' onchange event.

The form is submitted as usual by clicking on the "searchButton".

#### search.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['searchButton'])) { // Form was submitted by clicking on the "searchButton".
    $industry = $_POST['industry'];

    /*
     * Read the values of the posted skills checkboxes here. In the $_POST they are 
     * saved in an array like this:
     * 
     * [skills] => Array (
     *      [0] => 1
     *      [1] => 3
     * )
     */

    /*
     * Search in db and fetch the searching results into an array.
     * How you search is up to you. I'll use here just an array example.
     */
    $searchResults = [
        [
            'myarraykey1' => 13,
            'myarraykey2' => 'a value',
        //...
        ],
        [
            'myarraykey1' => 25,
            'myarraykey2' => 'other value',
        //...
        ],
        [
            'myarraykey1' => 37,
            'myarraykey2' => 'some other value',
        //...
        ],
    ];
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getSkillsList() {
                var industry = $('#industry').val();

                $.ajax({
                    method: 'post',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    url: 'getSkillsList.php',
                    data: {
                        industry: industry
                    },
                    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        $('#skillsList').html(response);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus + '<br />' + errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(function () {
                getSkillsList();

                $('#industry').on('change', function () {
                    getSkillsList()
                });

            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            body { padding: 30px; }
            button { padding: 5px 10px; font-size: 14px; background-color: #8daf15; color: #fff; border: none; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h3>Skills Search</h3>

        <form id="skillsSelectForm" action="" method="post">

            <select id="industry" name="industry">
                <option value="Administration" <?php echo isset($industry) && $industry === 'Administration' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                    Administration
                </option>
                <option value="Environment" <?php echo isset($industry) && $industry === 'Environment' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                    Environment & Agriculture
                </option>
            </select>

            <br/><br/>

            <div id="skillsList"></div>

            <br/>

            <button type="submit" name="searchButton">
                Search
            </button>

        </form>

        <?php
        if (isset($searchResults)) { // The form was not yet submitted, so the array doesn't exist yet.
            ?>
            <br/><hr/><br/>

            <div id="searchResults">
                <?php
                if ($searchResults) { // Array is not empty, e.g. search results were found.
                    foreach ($searchResults as $searchResult) {
                        $myArrayValue1 = $searchResult['myarraykey1'];
                        $myArrayValue2 = $searchResult['myarraykey2'];
                        //...
                        ?>
                        <div class="search-result-record">
                            <?php echo $myArrayValue1; ?> &raquo; <?php echo $myArrayValue2; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                    }
                } else { // Array is empty, e.g. no search results found.
                    ?>
                    <span class="no-search-results">
                        No search results found
                    </span>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

#### getSkillsList.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Get the industry - the value posted through the ajax 
 * request when the onchange event of the combobox or the window's onload event is raised.
 */
if (isset($_POST['industry'])) {
    $industry = $_POST['industry'];

    /*
     * Fetch the skills list from the db for the selected industry with an sql statement like:
     * "SELECT id, name FROM skills WHERE industry = $industry".
     * Note: use prepared statements!
     * 
     * The if-elseif case bellow is just a simulation of getting skills array based on a non-existent db.
     * In your case, fetch the skills from db and define the $skills array, without any if-elseif statement.
     */
    if ($industry === "Administration") {
        $skills = [
            [// 1st record
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Management',
            ],
            [// 2nd record
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Insurance',
            ],
            [// 3rd record
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'Financial and control',
            ],
        ];
    } elseif ($industry === "Environment") {
        $skills = [
            [// 1st record
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'Agronomy',
            ],
            [// 2nd record
                'id' => 2,
                'name' => 'Ansible',
            ],
            [// 3rd record
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'Business Case Development',
            ],
        ];
    }

    foreach ($skills as $skill) {
        $id = $skill['id'];
        $name = $skill['name'];
        ?>
        <label for="skill_<?php echo $id; ?>">
            <?php echo $name; ?>
        </label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" id="skill_<?php echo $id; ?>" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
        <br/>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem in your code is that your reloading the whole page to it's self inside the `$("#result")` element. That's why it looks like it executes twice.

When your  $().change event is triggered, it gets the whole html page and posts it inside the `#result` div element.

You can simplify the usage of GET method by trying this,

```
<form id="skillsSelectForm" role="form" method="get">
    <select id="industry" name="industry">
        <option value="">Select Industry</option>
        <option value="Administration">Administration</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="Charity">Charity</option>
        <option value="Healthcare">Healthcare</option>
    </select>
    <div id="ChkList"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search">
</form>


<script> 
    $('#industry').change(function() {
        var industry = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "getSkillList.php",
          data: { industry: industry },
          dataType: 'json'
          success: function(data) {
            if(data.length <> 0){
                var $elem  = $("#ChkList");
                var output = '';
                $elem.empty(); /* empty before appending the skills list */
                $.each(data, function(a,b){
                    output += "<label>"+b.skill+"</label><input type='checkbox' id='"+b.id+"' name=''><br>";
                })
                $elem.append(output); 
            }
          }
        });
    });
</script>


getSkillList.php

<?php 
    $industry_id = $_POST['industry'];
    /* You connection string here */
    $query = "Select * from skill_list where industry_id = $industry_id";
    $sth = mysqli_query($query);
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
    print json_encode($rows); 
    /* return the result of the query  $skilllist in json format */
?>
```